# 'g' & 'y' letters cut in "Question body goes here"

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

This is minor, but...
Looks like the line height may be insufficient as the bottom of the 'g' & 'y' letters gets cut:

v.0.1.16

> [image]

Comment: I think I remember seeing a request for making the question body text area size take up the amount of the space the 'tags' text area currently has. This looks like it would go hand in hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.